# what is this? #sthash.a3BsN8BD.dpbs

Tags: url, wordpress

I have a WordPress blog on my website, and I'm now noticing this stuff being appended to URLs:

```
#sthash.a3BsN8BD.dpbs
```

What is this? How do I remove it?

Comment: What plug-ins are you using?? It likely has to do with one of those. The question is how and where are you noticing this??

Comment: I am noticing this on a computer other than the one I use to administer the website. I"m wondering if it is a problem with this particular computer, or the website itself. Strange that I have two wordpress blogs on the one webserver and only one of the sites shows this

Comment: Could be a browser plug-in. It could be social buttons too! But that would only happen with a right-click copy on a link- the URL and stuff will be in the copy buffer. Or at least that is how it works here.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's from the ShareThis plugin when you enable the ‘Measure copy & shares of your site’s URLs’ option.